# Retorno de um for em uma lista python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Gostaria de usar o retorno de um for que lista arquivos de um diretório para usar em um comando do MySQL, mas não consigo pegar todos os arquivos. 
desde já agradeço a ajuda!

```
#Lista os arquivos do diretorio somente os arquivos de log
for i in glob.glob("C:\Backups\Logs\*.0000*"): 
     lista = [i]  

#Busca no banco de dados o ultimo Id inserido
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('Select * from logbin where Id = (select max(Id) from logbin)')
recordset = cursor.fetchall()

for record in recordset:
    print (record[1],"-->", record[2])

#Improta comandos do cmd - pip install plumbum.
from plumbum.cmd import mysqlbinlog
print  ( mysqlbinlog [lista, '-rC:\\Backups\\Logs\\Binlog.txt']())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código, você está recriando `lista` a cada iteração.
Coloque um `print(lista)`, conforme abaixo, e verá o que está acontecendo.

```
for i in glob.glob("C:\Backups\Logs\*.0000*"): 
     lista = [i]  
     print(lista)
```

A saída será algo do tipo:

```
['C:\Backups\Logs\asdf.0000asdf']
['C:\Backups\Logs\qwer.0000qwer']
['C:\Backups\Logs\aaar.000023232']
```

Ou seja, está criando 3 listas neste caso, uma lista para cada arquivo existente no diretório de logs.

Para gerar uma única lista com todos os arquivos retornados pelo `glob`, pode fazer assim:

```
lista = glob.glob('C:\Backups\Logs\*.0000*')
print (lista)
```

A saída é uma única lista:

```
['C:\Backups\Logs\asdf.0000asdf','C:\Backups\Logs\qwer.0000qwer','C:\Backups\Logs\aaar.000023232']
```